# Computing $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x}{x^{4}+1} dx$ using complex analysis.

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, improper-integrals, singular-integrals

I want to compute $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x}{x^{4}+1} dx$$ using complex analysis. Now the first thing that strikes me is that $f(x)$ is not an even function. So this troubles me a bit since I would normally use

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x)dx = \frac{1}{2} \left[\lim_{R \rightarrow \infty} \int_{-R}^{R} f(z)dz + \int_{C_{R}}f(z)dz \right],
$$
where $C_{R}$ is the semi cirle connecting $R$ to $-R$ in the positive imaginary part. Now we see that we have to compute the singularities of $f(z)$, which we can do by computing the fourth root of $z$. We then find
$$
\begin{align*}
z^{4} &= e^{i (\pi + 2n\pi)} \\
z &= e^{i ( \frac{\pi}{4} + \frac{n\pi}{2} )}
\end{align*}.
$$

Since we are only interested in singularities above the real line, we find 
$z_{0} = e^{i \frac{\pi}{4}}$ and $z_{1} = e^{i \frac{3\pi}{4}}$.

Then we let $p(z) = z$ and $q(z) = z^{4}+1$, which makes $q'(z) = 4z^{3}$. 
We then compute $p(z_{0}), q(z_{0})$ and $q'(z_{0})$ and finally $\frac{p(z)}{q'(z)}$ which equals the residue at $z_{0}$.

However, when I do the above I find
$\text{Res}(z_{0}) = - \frac{i}{4}$ and $\text{Res}(z_{1}) = \frac{i}{4}$ but this would make the integral equal zero since $2\pi i (\frac{i}{4} - \frac{i}{4})=0$.

Can anybody point me to my mistake? Also, when would find the value for this integral, I would argue we can not simply take half of it, since the initial function is not even. How would we fix that?

Comment: Using $u=x^2$, you will have an easy integral $\int \frac{1}{u^2+1}du$. This is no need to use residue method.

Comment: but I would like to use complex analysis to derive it anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So i would take the following contour:
$[0,R],$ $C_R$ and $[iR,0]$ where $C_R$ connects $R$ and $iR.$ So, instead of a semicircle, you have a quarter of a circle. Notice that, by doing this, just one of your singularities is inside, mainly $e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}$ hence your integral
$$\int _{[0,R]}+\int _{C_R}+\int _{[iR,0]}=2\pi i\frac{-i}{4}=\frac{\pi}{2}.$$ Check that  the integral vanishes in $C_R$ and make a change of variable, perhaps, $y=ix$ to convert the integral in $[iR,0]$ to an integral in $[0,R].$

Comment: WolframAplha would say $\int_0^{\infty} x/(x^4+1)\,dx=\pi/4$

Comment: @georg Probably because there are two integrals on the left that do not vanish and with the change of variable they both contribute a half. So this would agree with WolframAlpha

Comment: @xpaul Sorry but i do not see it. How do you get that $-1$?

Comment: Sorry, my calculation is wrong.

Comment: @Phicar I do not quite get your comment for Georg. Also, I see how your computations leads to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ but I do not see why you can simply take a contour that is half of what I would normally use ( a contour from -R to R and the upper semicircle to connect those two points). And why could I not use this standard contour (apart from that it leads me to zero, I do not see how this is 'wrong') Could you help me out?

Comment: @Steven Usually taking contours is a matter of practice. Your function, being odd, will cancel as you pointed out by computing the poles, so you would like to exclude one of the poles. It is not that you are wrong, is that that contour does not help. Taking different contours lead you to different integrals in the complex plane.

Comment: @Phicar Okay, that makes sense. But I always assumed the translation of the domain from $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}$ was 'kept' by taking the integral $\int_{-R}^{R}$. I guess I was wrong all the time and the shape of this contour does not matter at all, as long as all singularties are within it.

Answer (score 0):

It's somewhat easier with a "compromise" proof that substitutes before using complex analysis. The integral is$$\frac12\int_0^\infty\frac{du}{u^2+1}=\frac14\int_{\Bbb R}\frac{du}{u^2+1}=\frac{\pi i}{2}\lim_{u\to i}\frac{1}{u+i}=\frac{\pi}{4}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, computing an integral $\int_a^b f(x)\;dx$ by residues will only work if $x=a$ and $x=b$ are special points for $f(x)$.

If, for example, $b$ is not a special point, then you are essentially computing the **indefinite** integral.  If there is not nice formula for the indefinite integral, then trying to do it by residues will fail.